# Wallet system on Mobile Dapps

Tags: solidity, wallets, dapp-development, mobile-wallet

I want to develop a mobile decentralized application with flutter but I have a few questions in my mind. Well, I want to store data on the blockchain through smart contracts. So, I have to connect a wallet to the profile or generate a wallet to do this. I did a lot of research about generating an account or connecting an existing account but I couldn't find anything about it. So this is my question;

- How can I connect my wallet or generate a wallet to log in to the mobile app.